# Tensorflow: How to compute Quadratic input for activation function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

Most layers in tensorflow are of the form y=\phi(w^Tx+b).

[image: y=\phi(w^Tx+b)]

What I want to implement is a layer of the form y=\phi(x^TWx+w^Tx+b).

[image: y=\phi(x^TWx+w^Tx+b)]

A generic implementation of the former is shown below.

```py
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, order, units=32, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.parameter = parameter

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # delay definition of self.w to build() to make sure the shape matches the input.
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        # delay definition of self.b to build() to make sure the shape matches the input.
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Compute w^Tx+b
        pre_activation = tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
        # Take w^Tx+b and compute \phi(w^Tx+b)
        post_activation = my_activation_function(pre_activation, self.parameter)
        return post_activation

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"parameter": self.parameter})
        return config
```

At first glace I thought that the latter could be implemented by

```py
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, order, units=32, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.parameter = parameter

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # delay definition of self.W to build() to make sure the shape matches the input.
        self.W = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        # delay definition of self.w to build() to make sure the shape matches the input.
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        # delay definition of self.b to build() to make sure the shape matches the input.
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        # Compute x^TWx+w^Tx+b
        pre_activation = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.matmul(inputs, self.W)) + tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b
        # Take w^Tx+b and compute \phi(x^TWx+w^Tx+b)     
        post_activation = my_activation_function(pre_activation, self.parameter)
        return post_activation

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({"parameter": self.parameter})
        return config
```

However this does not work. Tensorflow works with batches, so the `inputs` to the `call` method is matrix of shape `(batch_size, input_vector_size)` instead of just a vector. In the case that y=\phi(w^Tx+b), this works out just fine. In my y=\phi(x^TWx+w^Tx+b) case I get errors because the dimensions no longer match.

I tried replacing `tf.matmul(inputs, tf.matmul(inputs, self.W))` with tensordots and other methods, but the main issue is that `inputs` has shape `(batch_size, input_vector_size)` and this multiplication is bound to give a result of the shape `(batch_size, batch_size, self.units)` instead of the desired `(batch_size, self.units)`.

With what should I replace the `pre_activation = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.matmul(inputs, self.W)) + tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b` so that I get a result of the shape `(batch_size, self.units)`?